# Spyder Module Import

Tags: python, import, module, spyder

I am trying to import cv2 module in Spyder.app but somehow it does not import. By the way I am able to import it in a terminal. Can anyone of you guys please help me?

Comment: Compare the result of `import sys; print sys.path` in the context where it works and the context where it doesn't work.

Comment: You can try to compare your imports to your actual files. Maybe there are namespace conflicts or you import the wrong packages. Try:
`import your_module; print your_module.__file__`.

Comment: Where do you execute your code from? Is it in the same directory like your main file? 
If not open your file in the directory where you "main" file is and execute it from there.

Comment: What do you mean by main file? I have a .py file I want to execute. Does it matter where it is located? Besides I am also trying to import the module in interpreter and it gives me error.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need to do:

1. Open a terminal and run `python` or `ipython`.
2. In there execute these two commands:

   `import sys`

   `sys.executable`
3. Copy the output of the last command
4. Open Spyder and go to

   `Spyder > Preferences > Console > Advanced settings > Python Executable`

   Select the option

   `Use the following Python interpreter`

   and paste there the result of step 3 (this option is only available in Spyder 2.2.3 or newer).
5. Finally go to `Interpreters > Open a Python interpreter`. This will open a new console that will be running the same Python version that you use in a terminal.

Comment: I did it but it did not work. I got '/usr/bin/python' after the second step and did what you listed. Any idea?

Comment: What happens when you run this command in the Spyder interpreter: `import sys; sys.path`?

Comment: I get directories like Python2.7/site-packages. What was it supposed to output?

Comment: Please gave me the full output. It will show me if you have selected the right python interpreter or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
Ubuntu 1804, 
Python 3.6.5, Spyder 3.2.8.

Could load e.g. quandl and other package in terminal virtual env but not in spyder despite playing with PYTHONPATH and directories for ages.

Resolved with:

```
conda install ipykernel cloudpickle
```