# Python Quandl in Spyder

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas, spyder, quandl

Spyder is working wonderfully with numpy and pandas, but with Quandl I get the following error (in spyder):

```
>>> import Quandl
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Quandl
```

Yet from the terminal Quandl installed without issue:

```
$ sudo easy_install quandl
Password:
Searching for quandl
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/quandl/
Best match: Quandl 1.8.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/Q/Quandl/Quandl-1.8.1.tar.gz#md5=f67bef937eb7522d70cf39ed0de740c1
Processing Quandl-1.8.1.tar.gz
Running Quandl-1.8.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-BEwINw/Quandl-1.8.1/egg-dist-tmp-aBuphk
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Adding Quandl 1.8.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Quandl-1.8.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for quandl
Finished processing dependencies for quandl
```

and I can also readily use the library from the terminal directly (in python2.7):

```
$ python2.7
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Quandl
>>> data= Quandl.get(['GOOG/NASDAQ_AAPL.4','GOOG/NASDAQ_MSFT.4'])
No authentication tokens found: usage will be limited.
See www.quandl.com/api for more information.
Returning Dataframe for  [u'GOOG.NASDAQ_AAPL.4', u'GOOG.NASDAQ_MSFT.4']
>>> data
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 8294 entries, 1981-03-11 00:00:00 to 2014-01-03 00:00:00
Data columns (total 2 columns):
GOOG.NASDAQ_AAPL - Close    8294  non-null values
GOOG.NASDAQ_MSFT - Close    7027  non-null values
dtypes: float64(2)
```

Any input on why Spyder would not be working with Quandl?

Must have been someone who tried to climb this mountain before me.

---

Solution went undiscovered when looking through stackoverflow, but was pointed out to me by the google group:

[answer here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485787/spyder-module-import/20485970#20485970)

Comment: Just a thought: Can you restart Spyder and check?

Comment: @NipunBatra - rebooted Spyder. still same issue unfortunately.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) Are you using our Mac native app? I mean the one you get from our dmg installer?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba i referenced your solution in my answer.

Comment: Great! Happy coding then :-)

Comment: @CarlosCordoba yes but I ended up switching to PyCharm :(

Answer (score 1):

I initially wrote `Quandl` (capitalized) and got an error, as it seems you are doing. It works lowercase for me (`import quandl`).

The python code from the quandl homepage is wrong on this point:

```
Quandl.get("OFDP/FUTURE_VX6", trim_start="2004-05-19", trim_end="2014-10-16")
```

Because they use a capitalized Q.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem in Anaconda Python after downgrading from 3.5 to 3.4.

I tried using both `pip install quandl` and `conda install quandl` (Anaconda-specific) as well as some other variants such as uninstalling and reinstalling.

I the end I realized the old value `Quandl` was cached. After removing the `Anaconda/Lib/site-packages/Qandl` folder entirely (after uninstalling) the `pip install quandl` worked as it should.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Just use import quandl and NOT import Quandl and it'll work.
I had the same problem.
Best

Comment: Good on you for answering a 4 year old question

Answer (score 0):

what recently worked for me was downloading the quandl package from python on the terminal, then from the Anaconda navigator/Environments going to not installed packages andfinding quandl there and installing it. then upon retarting spyder, import quandl showed no error

Answer (score -1):

you could just use the CSV links and download manually using url

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/OFDP/FUTURE_VX1.csv?&trim_start=2004-05-03&trim_end=2014-01-07&sort_order=desc')
html = response.read()
```

then parse appropriately