# CV2 module n Spyder.app

Tags: python, spyder

I tried to import cv2 in Spyder IDE but my kernel 'died'. Then I followed the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485787/spyder-module-import) but I have the following error message:

*Either:
Your IPython frontend and kernel versions are incompatible or
You don't have IPython installed in your external interpreter.*

Since I have the IPython installed then IPython frontend and kernel versions are incompatible.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Has anyone else faced the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late, but check your Spyder > preference > console >advanced setting

Choose the correct python executable and correct python startup replacement, then it should work. Sometimes people chose a specific startup file and executable binary in anther environment instead of the default ones.